# Capture system shortcut keys

Tags: c, x11

If I press option/meta key and left/right arrow my X11 desktop environment will tile the current window to the left/right and the keystroke will never reach my app. What can I do so I can receive the keystroke? (My app is sometimes run fullscreen). If possible can I prevent the keystrokes from being a shortcut (specifically while my app is in fullscreen mode)?

I tried XGrabKey and friends but I wasn't able to receive anything that's a shortcut. I suspect my question is possible because virtual machines seem to receive the keystrokes

Comment: This is tagged for c language so I was hoping to find some c code to review and offer assistance.  Was c tagged by accident?  (I think it can be undone if yes?) Else -- please post what code you've done so far and maybe there will be more responses from the community.  thx....

Comment: @Kz2023 the linux API is in C and I'm asking about the API. You can be C compatible w/o writing C code

Comment: understood and agreed.  Thx for clarifying back to me.   Best wishes with everything, Adam.

Comment: X11 does not tile, a (tiling) window manager on the other hand does. A window manager should provide an interface to modify (set) hotkeys, have a look for that. You can (more or less) solve it by grabbing the window but then you'll have to notify the WM to leave that window alone (WM_TRANSIENT_FOR Property and/or Override Redirect Flag), Whether the results will satisfy you or not, depends, because the WM could reserve some hotkeys (events) to itself and will prevent your app from receiving those sort of events. In short, you have to consult the specs of your WM.

Comment: Another solution would be to bypass X (and therefore the WM) completely: evdev (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evdev) and [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libevdev/))

Comment: Never forget: do not fight the window manager (you'll lose)!